# which programing language and development enviroment are the most recommended for OCR?

Tags: ocr

i want to crate a simple OCR project,it wil be an android APP
i want the APP tp scan the list of ingredients of some food package and translate it to a list of words.
which programing language and development enviroment are the most recommended for such project and why?